# Service Bus Queue Message Dead Letters But Code Still Runs

Tags: azureservicebus

We have a `Function App` listening to a `Service Bus Queue`. The logic inside of this function can take upwards of 20 minutes to run depending on the amount of data. What's odd is that messages are being dead-lettered, but the function's code (as long as it doesn't time out) continues to be run to completion. We have code that renews the lock (lock duration is 1 minute) but I'm not sure why it's DLQ'ing so early but also continuing to run the Function App code after being sent to DLQ. I thought that if a message is sent to DLQ, that's it, the function stops running any subsequent logic. Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

-Edit for additional information

We are using the `EP1` premium plan. The delivery count is 1 (we didn't want to keep retrying expensive logic if it failed but I could be wrong in that regard so please let me know if that's the wrong way to go).

The code that was created uses a class that inherits from `IDistributedLockManager` to renew/release locks.

Comment: Is this Consumption or Premium Functions app? Or is this hosted in another service (AKS, App Service)? What's the delivery count on the queue? How do you configure your Function trigger to extend the lock?

Comment: Let me update the question with the appropriate information.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `IDistributedLockManager`. The way functions handle anything > 5 minutes is by extending the lock using ASB. That's a configuration in the `host.json` for your ASB triggers. Also, you should increase the lock duration from 1min to 5 if you require a longer time to process.

Comment: Got it, I was thinking of extending the lock duration but hadn't tried it as I wasn't sure of any side effects it may create. I'll try that out and post back. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, it's possible that the message is being dead-lettered due to the lock expiring before the function completes its processing.

The default lock duration is 30 seconds. If the function takes longer time to process the message, then the lock will get expire and the message will be dead-lettered.

There is a chance of possible that the message is being dead-lettered due to other reasons, such as `exceeding the maximum delivery count`, or due to errors while `processing subscription rules`.

> And the delivery count, setting it to 1 means that the message will be dead lettered after a single delivery attempt if it fails to be processed successfully. This is useful if you don't want to keep retrying expensive logic, but it also means that the message will be dead-lettered if there are any transient errors that could be resolved with a retry.

Code reference from the [blog](https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure-service-bus-netstandard/lock-renewal/)

```
 while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
              now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
              remainingTime = msg.LockedUntil - now;

               var bffr = TimeSpan.FromTicks(Math.Min(remainingTime.Ticks / 2, MaxRenewBufferDuration.Ticks));
               var renew_After = remainingTime - bffr;

               await Task.Delay(renew_After, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    try
                    {
                        await processMessageEventArgs.RenewMessageLockAsync(msg, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        attempts = 0;
                        Log.Info($"{message.MessageId}: Lock renewed until {msg.LockedUntil:s}Z.");
                    }
                    catch (ServiceBusException e) when (e.Reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.MessageLockLost)
                    {
                        Log.Error($"{msg.MessageId}: Lock lost.", e);
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) when (!(e is OperationCanceledException))
                    {
                        ++attempts;
                        Log.Warn($"{msg.MessageId}: Failed to renew lock (#{attempts:N0}), if lock cannot be renewed within {msg.LockedUntil:s}Z message will reappear.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) when (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Fatal($"{msg.MessageId}: RenewLock-Token: " + e.Message, e);
            }
```

To troubleshoot the issue, you can check the [dead-letter reason and description properties](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues.md#moving-messages-to-the-dlq) of the message.

[image]

For further information refer to [MSDoc.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/includes/v3-csharp-sdk.md)

Comment: If a message is added to DLQ, does it continue to run until it completes/function times out? We have our messages being sent to DLQ, but the logic of the function app continues to execute after they're sent there.